# GitHub actions fails when it is triggered for pull_request

Tags: git, github, github-actions

I am trying to make a GitHub Action that accepts pull requests to the beta branch from certain branches and accepts pull requests to the main branch from the beta branch only.

As I am closing the pull request automatically, I am using superbrothers/close-pull-request@v3.0.0 which only runs successfully for pull_request_target event.

And I have set the trigger to pull_request_target only. But it gets triggered on pull_request event as well. And I have seen it is an expected behavior.

But on my jobs, I have put condition to run only for pull_request_target event. But for some reason, it is not working.

```
name: CI


# Controls when the workflow will run
on:
  # Triggers the workflow on pull request events but only for the "main" branch
  pull_request_target:
    branches: [ "main", "beta" ]
    types: [opened, reopened]

  # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
  workflow_dispatch:

env:
  GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN}}
  
# A workflow run is made up of one or more jobs that can run sequentially or in parallel
jobs:
  # This workflow contains a single job called "build"
  if_beta:
    if: github.base_ref == 'beta' && github.event.action == 'pull_request_target'
    permissions: write-all
    # The type of runner that the job will run on
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:

      - uses: actions-ecosystem/action-regex-match@v2
        id: regex-match
        with:
          text: ${{ github.head_ref }}
          regex: '^v\d+\.\d+\.\d+-alpha'
        
      - name: Reject if it is not from release branch
        if: ${{ steps.regex-match.outputs.match == '' }}
        uses: superbrothers/close-pull-request@v3
        with:
          comment: "beta branch can have pull requests only from release branch"
          
  if_main:
    if: github.base_ref == 'main' && github.event.action == 'pull_request_target'
    permissions: write-all
    # The type of runner that the job will run on
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    
      - name: Print
        run: echo ${{ github.event.action }}        
        
      - name: Reject if it is not from beta branch
        if: ${{ github.head_ref != 'beta' }} && ${{ github.event.action == 'pull_request_target' }}
        uses: superbrothers/close-pull-request@v3.0.0
        with:
          comment: "main branch can have pull requests only from beta branch"
```

Here is the error I am getting

[image: Error]

Comment: Use `github.event_name == 'pull_request_target'`. Example: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#example-usage-of-the-github-context.

Comment: See https://github.com/superbrothers/close-pull-request/blob/78473a7a3aa62ce59800b0adf905ffc4dc2ec746/dist/index.js#L25-L30.

Answer (score 0):

The action [superbrothers/close-pull-request](https://github.com/superbrothers/close-pull-request) checks  `github.event_name` for `pull_request_target`.

See [here](https://github.com/superbrothers/close-pull-request/blob/78473a7a3aa62ce59800b0adf905ffc4dc2ec746/dist/index.js#L25-L30) in its source code:

```js
const context = github.context;

if (context.eventName !== "pull_request_target") {
  throw errors.ignoreEvent;
}
```

So, you need to use `github.event_name` from the [`github` context](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#github-context).